# Makefile - Erro: file truncated

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

i have a simple Makefile:

```
CC=g++

CFLAGS= -Wall -std=c++11 -M -MF dependencyFileName.d -c

objects = Table.o LimitedTable.o aDimension.o test.o

edit: $(objects)
    g++ -o edit $(objects)

test.o: LimitedTable.o Table.o aDimension.o test.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) test.cpp -o test.o

LimitedTable.o: LimitedTable.cpp LimitedTable.hpp Table.o aDimension.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) LimitedTable.cpp -o LimitedTable.o

aDimension.o: aDimension.cpp aDimension.cpp Table.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) aDimension.cpp -o aDimension.o

Table.o: Table.cpp Table.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Table.cpp -o Table.o

clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

and I get this error:

```
marius@marius-Lenovo-Y50-70 ~/Documents $ make clean
rm -f *.o
marius@marius-Lenovo-Y50-70 ~/Documents $ make edit
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -M -MF dependencyFileName.d -c Table.cpp -o Table.o
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -M -MF dependencyFileName.d -c aDimension.cpp -o aDimension.o
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -M -MF dependencyFileName.d -c LimitedTable.cpp -o LimitedTable.o
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -M -MF dependencyFileName.d -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -o edit Table.o LimitedTable.o aDimension.o test.o
Table.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [edit] Error 1
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong ?
Could a wrong include in one of the files be a reason for this error ?

Comment: "File truncated" sounds like "unexpected end-of-file." What if you manually regenerate it by running `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c Table.cpp -o Table.o`, without `make`? And if you try to link that with a trivial, "hello, world" `main`?

Comment: ok i will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some problems with the way you handle your dependency file, but first:

> I have a simple Makefile

No you don't. The amount of boilerplate code is way too high, and adding any file to your projet will require you to manually edit that makefile again.

Your Makefile should be boiled down to this:

```
SRC         :=  $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ         :=  $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
DEP         :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d)
CPPFLAGS    :=  -MMD -MP
CXXFLAGS    :=  -std=c++11 -Wall

edit: $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $^ -o $@

-include $(DEP)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(DEP)
```

Here you :

- avoid repeating yourself too much,
- make good use of make's implicit rules to save time,
- use the right built-in variables instead of overriding the wrong ones,
- correctly handle dependency files creation **and** actually use them to prevent manual recompilation,
- won't need to edit the makefile when adding a `.cpp` or `.hpp` file to your project.

Also, that should fix your problem. **Don't forget to clean before trying to compile again after such an error ("file truncated") occurred.**

Comment: ok that look way better thank you :) but what does wildcard mean? does it take all the source files in the current directory ?

Comment: Yes that's it, you can remove it if you need to specify each file to compile. You can also specify a relative path, like `$(wildcard src/*.cpp)`.

Comment: and make will automatically identify the dependencies between the inherited files ?

Comment: Since the dependencies are created by your compiler (through the `-MMD -MP` switches) and included in your makefile (through the `-include $(DEP)`), yes it will be handled automatically.